# No idea why Internet not working 16.04

Tags: networking

I was connecting to the Internet via USB Modem. Recently I upgraded packages including kernel and now I cannot use Internet after powering on my computer from suspend mode. Even updating packages isn't working (in Terminal).  But in the Home page of the modem, it says "Connected". :[image: home page of the modem]

I have to do fresh boot all the time.

What should I do?

Comment: Is it a Mac OS?

Comment: No It's not. It's Ubuntu 16.04